# ArcGIS export mosaic seamline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, export, geotiff-tiff, mosaic

I created a mosaic from multiple overlapping GeoTif files in ArcMap 10.2. Than I created seamlines between the images to define which part of the scene is taken from which original image. Now, I want to export them as one georeferenced tif such that the seamlines are regarded. 
Does anyone know how?

Comment: It's not that hard to make a new mosaic dataset (in either the same or new geodatabase) pointing to the same data, it would probably be quicker to do that. If you're only exporting it to a single image then you don't need to build pyramids (overviews). When you say 'seamlines are regarded' do you mean you want to see them or not see them?

Comment: What I want is that the data is "copied"/exported to a new tif file. The seamlines should define, where the original images are "cut". As a result, I need noting else than the entire composed scene as tiff

Comment: I'm not 100% sure the seamlines can be included, your best bet is to use the ArcMap right-click on layer then select data::export data then select 'use renderer', that should give you exactly what you see on screen... it works for 1 band images with a colour ramp (converts to RGB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how I solved it (intuitively easy): Set the properties how seamlines should be treated for the mosaic drawing in ArcMap in the mosaic properties. Than, right click on the mosaic Image layer and hit Export Data. The result is as wanted.